# Reach out to Code Sandbox or some other mechanism for avoiding these links

Tags: discussion, code

I've seen a few questions where the code is all in a markdown link with an image to Code Sandbox:

```
[![Edit new](https://codesandbox.io/static/img/play-codesandbox.svg)](https://codesandbox.io/s/new)
```

And it renders like this:

[image: Edit new]

We already blacklist jsfiddle with out additional code, can we do something similar for these?

Comment: Does anyone else get annoyed by jsfiddle links in general, especially now that SO has a really nice snippet editor? I mean, if it were a different language then sure - but jsfiddle is pretty much exactly what SO snippets offer...

Comment: @Shadow: They're not exactly the same. A Stack Snippet augments a post, and is not designed to stand on its own. This is evident in the fact that you cannot fork a Stack Snippet in-place; you can only import it into the answer field, where, if you do use it, you're expected to post it as part of your own answer. A fiddle (I'm going by the [genericized name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generic_trademark) here, not referring to JSFiddle specifically) is a self-contained sandbox (as the name Code Sandbox itself suggests) that can be edited, forked, etc without any dependence on a host post.

Comment: Having code on an external site (e.g. JSFiddle, CodeSandbox, and many others) to *augment* a post (as BoltClock mentioned) can be beneficial. You have to link to it somehow. However, using the CodeSandbox image as the link strikes me as purely advertising and could imply that SE is approving/endorsing using that site. I'm tempted to go with calling it "spam", but I don't think it rises to the level of calling a whole post spam just because someone, unaffiliated, happens to use that site.

Comment: @Makyen yea its not spam, but a few people are just linking with no other context in the post.

Comment: Codesandbox is amazing to quickly present some code based on dependencies. Sorry, but SO snippets are invalid for such cases.

Comment: @Patrickkx if your question/answer is not including the code, it will get closed/deleted, no matter how great is your external tool for dependencies.

Comment: I have suggestion: SO should replicate (in their snippets or other tools) all the functionality of all the external systems (including the dependency system of Codesandbox) and then SO should automatically suck all the content from the references to the external systems (e.g. Codesandbox) during the saving of the question. In such scenario SO will be able to allow questions without code but with references to the external systems only.

Comment: @TomR Excellent idea, except the copyrights are different. Importing ppls fiddles into Stacksnippets (because fiddles can be deleted, changed or otherwise become irrelevant to the question) completely changes their copyright and may not be what OP wants. However they should all be recommended to do so